# check if relation exists has_one mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, :type => String

  has_one :response
end

class Response
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :content, :type => String

  belongs_to :question

end
```

console:

```
1.9.3p448 :014 > Question.where(:response => nil).size
 => 3 
1.9.3p448 :016 > Question.where(:response.ne => nil).size
 => 0
```

However all `questions` has one `response` created and associated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID field is stored in the child object only, therefore `Question` has no knowledge of its `Response` (no `response_id` field).

You can achieve the goal like this:

```
Response.ne(question_id: nil).map(&:question)
```

Or, to fetch questions without responses:

```
Question.not.in(id: Response.pluck(:question_id))
```

Comment: Alternative for the same query: `Question.where(:id.nin => Response.pluck(:question_id))`